# ITIN exception 1c- passive income bank letter

Tags: itin

In order to apply for an ITIN using exception 1c, I require a letter from the bank as follows:

1(c) A signed letter from the bank on its official letterhead, displaying your name and stating that you have opened an individual deposit account that is subject to IRS information reporting and/or federal tax withholding on the interest generated during the current tax year.

I have had a bank account for 3 years but they are unable to produce this letter as it does not appear in their templates. I have gone up the chain but no luck. Can anyone tell me where they have been banking that has given them this letter.

Thanks
Diana

Comment: Does the bank require you provide them the ITIN?

Comment: Here's the IRS [web page](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw7/ar02.html) with the instructions. Ah, see page 36 of this IRS [pdf](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1915.pdf) for a sample letter.

Answer (score 2):

You also need enough interest income to cause a filing requirement for the bank. With interest rates sitting at .1%, you need an account with a balance of $10,000 or more all year.